# Variable String: Need to get a substring located between delimiter

Tags: sql

I have a column data in sql.

```
Row1= {office Visit|01/09/19 12:35|Atonde.Adedayo O|Draft|{20190123.155152|1051|R|}}
Row2= {Labaratory Visit|01/09/19 12:35|Amar Shetty O|Draft|{20190123.155152|1051|R|}}
```

Etc...
I have this variable length data in each row.
I want to extract the names like    `Atonde.Adedayo O`  &  `Amar Shetty O`
These names are located between the delimiter | 
Please help me resolve this problem.

Thanks, 
Palak

Comment: Always tag the database you are using!

Comment: The answer would totally depend on the particular database you are using (e.g. MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, Postgres).  But, in any case, your table design has a smell, and you should not be storing such pipe delimited data like this, _unless_ you only need to ever retrieve the entire string at once.

Comment: In Postgres: `split_part(the_column, '|', 3)` but storing delimited values in a single column is bad design to begin with

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2016+ then you can use this trick:

```
DECLARE @Row1 VARCHAR(200) = '{office Visit|01/09/19 12:35|Atonde.Adedayo O|Draft|{20190123.155152|1051|R|}}';
DECLARE @Row2 VARCHAR(200) = '{Labaratory Visit|01/09/19 12:35|Amar Shetty O|Draft|{20190123.155152|1051|R|}}';
DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(200);

SELECT @Result = T.value FROM
(SELECT TOP 3 * FROM String_Split(@Row1, '|')) AS T;

PRINT @Result;

SELECT @Result = T.value FROM
(SELECT TOP 3 * FROM String_Split(@Row2, '|')) AS T;

PRINT @Result;
```